# how to make a typewritter text effect to loop using css

Tags: css

Hello am trying to do a typewriter text effect on my page using css, i got a particular snippet that gives a typewriting effect but it do-sent loop, and i need it to loop

This is the initial code am working with

```
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>The cat and the hat.</h1>
</div>

/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange; }
}
```

Can some one please expatiate how to make this loop, i read online that you need to include the infinite word into it but i dnt knw where to add this please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` to `.typewriter h1` will loop it.

```css
/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */

.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}
/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>The cat and the hat.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: when i run it here it works but when i run it on my browser it dosent, anyways thanks